# How can I force positive auto generated hibernate primary keys

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate 4.3.8. on Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and MS SQL. For creating numeric primary keys I have used the following code :

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "t_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "t_gen", sequenceName = "T_SEQ")
  private long id;
```

So far so good. But I need to generate only positive values of IDs under all conditions. How can I force Hibernate to generate only positive ID's on each database (MS SQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle) ?

Comment: Are you actually getting negative values on some database with this code?

Comment: @PredragMaric currently not, but nowhere is quaranteed that it cannot happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps;

If allocationSize is not declared on the entity side, as default allocation size is 50 ALL sequences  MUST declare INCREMENT BY 50 on the DB side.

Reference Link:
http://skay-dev.blogspot.in/2013/09/hibernate-sequence-and-negative.html

Comment: Ok, I understand this. But why Hibernate generated  for my sequencies increment 1 on Oracle and PostgreSQL ? Is there some option to force Hibernate to generate sequencies with increment 50 ?

Comment: have you tried @SequenceGenerator( ..., allocationSize=n )

Comment: This does not helped, the DDL script has only create sequence T_SEQ;