# How can I force Hibernate to generate sequences with custom increment

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, ddl

I am using Hibernate 4.3.8 with JPA 2.1 and autogenerated ID's via sequencies by:

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "t_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "t_gen", sequenceName = "T_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 50)
  private long id;
```

Unfortunatelly the Hibernate generates for ORACLE the following DDL:

```
create sequence T_SEQ;
```

But I need increment by 50, see [How can I force positive auto generated hibernate primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607648/how-can-i-force-positive-auto-generated-hibernate-primary-keys) . How can I achieve this ?

EDIT:
I need to force Hibernate to generate such sequence with custom autoincrement in it's generated DDL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a sequence in ORACLE database :

**sql> create sequence T_SEQ incremented by 50;**

and specify that sequence name in @SequenceGenerator :

**@SequenceGenerator(name = "t_gen", sequenceName = "T_SEQ")**

I hope it will work fine.
Thanks.

Comment: This works, but I need Hibernate to generate DDL automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
sql>create sequence T_SEQ  
NOMAXvalue  
start with 1  
increment by 50  
nocache  
order;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that there is currently no possibility to do this. It is related to this Hibernate bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8008 .